# Using C# and Selenium, how do you select a SubMenu Item that is a hover link in IE?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, menu

I have searched several topics on Stack Overflow and other sites for several days trying to find the solution for this with no luck. I have a website I am trying to automate using C# Selenium and can not get Webdriver to click on this sub menu item link. How do you use XPath or other solution to click on this sub menu item?

You have to click on the Menu heading first to get the rest of the menu list to appear, then click on one of the options in the sub menu to get to the page. I am trying to click on "Ad Hoc POCNs" to display the sub menu item list which works fine using Webdriver Click() but then clicking on a sub menu item like "Create POCN by PO Number/Part Number" does not work.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="WUC_Menu1_divMenu" style="WIDTH: 780px;height: 18px;">
<GDC:Menu userType="B" type="main" hilitecolor="white" hilitebgcolor="black" normalcolor="White" normalbgcolor="#713400" normalendbgcolor="Black" noframes="yes" xmlns:GDC="company website taken out">
    <GDC:Menu type="horz" caption="Requisitions" href="" value="" normalbgcolor="#B58759">
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Create New Req" href="EditReq.aspx"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Unreleased Reqs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=P&amp;status=U&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="P" status="U"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Reqs Awaiting Auto Conversion" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=P&amp;status=A&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="P" status="A"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Reqs Awaiting Other Approval" href="ListReqsAwaitingOtherApproval.aspx?type=P&amp;status=I&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="P" status="I"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Rejected Reqs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=P&amp;status=R" mtype="P" status="R"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Cancelled Reqs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=P&amp;status=C" mtype="P" status="C"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Converted Reqs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=P&amp;status=P" mtype="P" status="P"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Copy Latest Req" href="CopyLatestReq.aspx"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Replicate Req" href="ReplicateReq.aspx"/>
    </GDC:Menu>
    <GDC:Menu type="horz" caption="Ad Hoc POCNs" href="" value="" normalbgcolor="#B58759">
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Create POCN by PO Number/Part Number" href="ListOpenPOs.aspx?CREATE=Y&amp;POCN=Y"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Create New POCN" href="ListOpenPOs.aspx?POCN=Y"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Unreleased POCNs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=C&amp;status=U&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="C" status="U"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="POCNs Awaiting Auto Conversion" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=C&amp;status=A&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="C" status="A"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="POCNs Awaiting Other Approval" href="ListReqsAwaitingOtherApproval.aspx?type=C&amp;status=I&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="C" status="I"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Rejected POCNs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=C&amp;status=R" mtype="C" status="R"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Cancelled POCNs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=C&amp;status=C" mtype="C" status="C"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Converted POCNs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=C&amp;status=P" mtype="C" status="P"/>
    </GDC:Menu>
    <GDC:Menu type="horz" caption="AutoGen POCNs" href="" value="" normalbgcolor="#B58759">
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="POCNs Awaiting Approver Selection" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=S&amp;status=S&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="C" status="S"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="POCNs Awaiting Auto Conversion" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=S&amp;status=H&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="C" status="H"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="POCNs Awaiting Other Approval" href="ListReqsAwaitingOtherApproval.aspx?type=S&amp;status=SI&amp;StartPage=N" mtype="C" status="SI"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Rejected POCNs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=S&amp;status=SR" mtype="C" status="SR"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Cancelled POCNs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=S&amp;status=SC" mtype="C" status="SC"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="Converted POCNs" href="ListReqs.aspx?type=S&amp;status=SP" mtype="C" status="SP"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="ByPass AutoGen" href="ByPassAutoGenPOCN.aspx"/>
        <GDC:Menu useView="true" type="vert" caption="AUTO POCN Process Errors" href="ListAutoGenPOCNProcessErrors.aspx" mtype="S" status="AUTO"/>
    </GDC:Menu>
</GDC:Menu>
    </div>
```

Here is my code:

```
//Click on the Ad Hoc POCNs to get the menu to appear and show sub menu options -- this works
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Ad Hoc POCNs']")).Click();

//I am trying to click on Create POCN by PO Number/Part - this does not work
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Create POCN by PO Number/Part Number']")).Click();
```

I have also tried

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='ListOpenPOs.aspx?CREATE=Y&amp;POCN=Y']")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.Name...
driver.FindElement(By.Link...
driver.FindElement(By.TagName...
driver.FindElement(By.ID...
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName...
```

The first click works fine. The second click does not work. I have tried XPath and a number of other OpenQA.Selenium.By.**__** to click on this sub menu link and nothing seems to work. I get the error "OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException : Element should have been select but was menu" when trying using SelectElement.

This HTML does not have the standard anchors and instead has GDC:Menu tags.

I thought XPath was for finding elements in XML or XLST but I am seeing where other engineers using XPath for finding HTML elements.

I have also tried Actions but maybe I am not getting my code right.

Also maybe I just don't have the proper XPath expression to get to the sub menu item.

Please help me find a solution by xpath or some other solution.

Comment: @sircapsalot that is the rendered HTML in the browser IE. It's of course not the entire HTML result. I used IE's Developers tool and they say "F12 tools displays HTML and CSS code as it is rendered in the browser, and not the strict HTML source".

Comment: When I use Firebug to inspect the rendered HTML here is the xPath I get to the element I am trying to Click():  /html/body/form/div[2]/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu[2]/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu/gdc:menu[2]/gdc:menu

Comment: I think you are going to need to use Actions to achieve what you are trying to do.  http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

don't forget to finish your action chain with .Build().Perform()  Actions move the mouse around.  Lots of StackOverflow questions with similar questions all point to this solution

Comment: @DaveBush I tried the below. I can't figure out the right xpath to pull a list where I can click on the sub menu item.
`var liPOCN = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[text()='Ad Hoc POCNs']"));//this gdcmenu displays the menu list after clicking it. I want the list of sub menu items after clicking it

Actions action = new Actions(driver);//simply my webdriver

action.MoveToElement(liPOCN[1]).Perform();//move to submenu link that needs to be clicked (first item in list Create POCNs

action.Click();`

I get Index out of range error so I think I am not pulling the list correctly.

Comment: @Dave Bush, also this question...although it may be similar...it is not. In the other questions there are traditional and standard tags. I have never seen a GDC:Menu tag. This question is more about how to get to the element to make it clickable. How would you write your action to get to that gdc:menu element. I tried several different techniques with no luck. Give it a shot!

Comment: But you say in your original question that the first select and click works. I'll have to look at this when I get home from work tonight.

Comment: Yeah..first click works, it is the menu heading. Once it is clicked, it expands the menu(gdc:menu) list. The gdc:menu list items ... I can not click. I tried a number of methods. Maybe I just don't have the correct xpath coded.

Comment: I've tried this one also but to no avail 'driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='WUC_Menu1_divMenu']//gdc:menu/gdc:menu[contains(@caption,'Create POCN']")).Click();' I get an error that says "OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : The xpath expression '//div[@id='WUC_Menu1_divMenu']//gdc:menu/gdc:menu[contains(@caption,'Create POCN']' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement"

Answer (score 0):

OK.. since I don't have the full implementation I'm going to take a stab at what you want with code that isn't compliled, but should be pretty darn close to what I think you need.

It may be that all you need is a Wait.  The following assumes your selectors work, but your element hasn't become visible prior to you trying to click it.  This will fix that problem.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,60); // wait 60 seconds
//Click on the Ad Hoc POCNs to get the menu 
//to appear and show sub menu options -- this works
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Ad Hoc POCNs']"));

wait.Until(x => 
    x.FindElements(
        By.XPath("//*[text()='Create POCN by PO Number/Part Number']"))
        .Count > 0)


//I am trying to click on Create POCN by PO Number/Part - this does not work
driver.FindElement(
    By.XPath("//*[text()='Create POCN by PO Number/Part Number']"))
        .Click();
```

If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to use Actions.  Again, assuming your selector is right (and I can't see any reason it wouldn't.  The first one works, the second should as well).

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,60); // wait 60 seconds
//Click on the Ad Hoc POCNs to get the menu 
//to appear and show sub menu options -- this works
var topElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Ad Hoc POCNs']"));

// just to be sure
wait.Until(x => 
    x.FindElements(
        By.XPath("//*[text()='Create POCN by PO Number/Part Number']"))
        .Count > 0)


//I am trying to click on Create POCN by PO Number/Part - this does not work
var secondElement = driver.FindElement(
    By.XPath("//*[text()='Create POCN by PO Number/Part Number']"));
var action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(secondElement).Click().Build().Perform();
```

If neither of those do the trick, maybe you could make a sample available so that I can get it working here and post the code.

Comment: Thanks Dave so much for the help. It is still not finding the Create POCN. It times out each time. By the way, not sure if it matters but both of these menu links have some sort of hover feature. When you hover over both of them, it seems like they get underlined - or their link appears. Maybe we have to hover over the second sub menu item first before initiating a click?

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried this one also but to no avail
>   'driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='WUC_Menu1_divMenu']//gdc:menu/gdc:menu[‌​contains(@caption,'Create
>   POCN']")).Click();' I get an error that says
>   "OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : The xpath expression
>   '//div[@id='WUC_Menu1_divMenu']//gdc:menu/gdc:menu[contains(@caption,'Create
>   POCN']' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement"

You cant use an XPath to do what you are trying to do, it wont evaluate to anything ever because you are telling selenium to look at every element at once. You can either use a for loop to evaluate it or a foreach.

```
//Get the number of items that exist in the menu drop down. 
int elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@id'WUC_Menu1_divMenu']/gdc:menu/gdc:menu[2]")).Count(); 
for(int i = 1; i <= elements; i++) 
{
    //Get the caption value using .GetAttribute 
    string caption = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id'WUC_Menu1_divMenu']/gdc:menu/gdc:menu[2]/gdc:menu[" + i + "]")).GetAttribute("caption");

    //An alternative to using the exact string would be 
    //if(caption.Contains("Create POCN"))

    if(caption == "Create POCN by PO Number/Part Number"))
    (
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='WUC_Menu1_divMenu']/gdc:menu/gdc:menu[2]/gdc:menu[" + i + "]")).Click();
    )
)
```

Another option would be to throw in some Javascript to force the elements to show up and then they are able to be interacted with on selenium's side. I agree with Dave though, using an action builder is best. You might want to look into how to properly chain events.

Comment: Thank you Ben for the help! Sorry to say this doesn't work either. I even tried a click() on the main menu first. I hadn't tried the IJavaScriptExecutor on this yet. I don't know what script it would be though. I see a few scripts on this page. I would have to email you guys the entire html or paste it on here. Would pasting the entire html publicly be safe since it is an internal web app?

Comment: I don't think we need ALL of the HTML and javascript, but we do need enough that the problem can be replicated.  Can you put a sample up on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Be sure that you are getting your elements to actually be in the dom / displayed / active before you try to view them. Keep in mind that you may have to set the css on some elements to ensure that they are actually available to interact with. Examples of this could be pages with an overlay, or elements with hidden attributes, or display: none items.

Comment: @Dave Bush here is the jsfiddle html. [jsfiddle html](http://jsfiddle.net/ErWSk/) I took out some key person names and URLs, company name for privacy.

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure I how I would code to insure I set the css on some elements to make sure they are available.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't run in FireFox or Chrome.

Comment: All the html and javascript is there. The website runs in our intranet and I had to remove some URLs, my name and company name to keep privacy - not a big deal just don't they'd appreciate me posting their code to a public forum. The menu items do not appear in FireFox. Not exactly the best web app to automate because it appears that the app needs to be updated. This application was written poorly if you ask me.